# How to Open Suggestion menu forcefully in autocomplete jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I want to open the suggestion menu of `autocomplete` upon clicking some button. How to do that?

```
var dropDown = $("<a class='showAll' title='Show all'/>")
                                    .insertAfter(this.element)
                                    .button({
                                        icons: {
                                            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                                        },
                                        text: false
                                    })
                                    .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                                    .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle")
                                    .click(function () {
//What I have to write here?
});
```

suppose this button is inside autocomplete _create function. so i have autocomplete input element by `this.element`
Now, how should I proceed?

**EDIT**: I don't want to call `search` event. I just want to open the suggestion menu simply.

Comment: Can you give us jsfiddle.net on what you want? Also specify what yopu have already tried

Comment: Suppose this is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8U6xq/4/

in 38number line I don't want to call `search` event but just want to `open` the suggestion menu.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this [JQUERY DEMO](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).
it also has the source code on how to code it.

As per comments i have tried some code sample at http://jsfiddle.net/UF8TV/

I was not able to get it working in your JSFiddle code (may be becuase there is no osurce and _renderItem  ).

you want to check the line numbers 84 to 90.

```
  if(input.val()=="Select"){
    input.val("");

    input.keydown();
    }else{
         input.autocomplete("widget").show();
    }
```

I think in your code snippet below code should work .

```
if(jQuery(visibleElement).val()=="Select"){
    jQuery(visibleElement).val("");    
    jQuery(visibleElement).keydown();

}else{
    jQuery(visibleElement).autocomplete("widget").show();
}
```

You might even only need `jQuery(visibleElement).autocomplete("widget").show();`

Comment: I have followed that manual only. There at the button click event, there is call to `search` event. I dont want to call that event but open directly the suggestion menu. and `._trigger("open")` is not working.

Comment: if you wont call search from where you are expecting the things to show in suggestion menu?

Comment: Because I have called _renderMenu and appended with proper value. Now all the results are available there. So I don't need to call `search`.

Comment: in your jsfiddel there is no call to _renderMenu

Comment: No, I am just telling you that we can do that.